Prisma GENERATE - Error: Generator "/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/generator-build/index.js" failed
While deployment on ECS service I'm getting an Error:

Generator "/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/generator-build/index.js"
failed

It's working on my local computer, but I'm getting this issue during deployment of the Task in ECS.
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine as base

FROM base as deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN  npm install --omit-dev


FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# prisma
RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production


COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY prisma/ /app/prisma/

RUN mkdir .next && \
    chown -R nextjs:nodejs .next


COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

EXPOSE 8080 

ENV PORT 8080 
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "node server.js"]


How can I debug this issue?

The question doesn't really make sense, because you don't deploy a Dockerfile to ECS. You build an image from the Dockerfile, you push that image to an image repository, and then you have ECS pull that image from the repository and run it. Your error is during the build phase, when you build the docker image from the Dockerfile. The build phase, running docker build, can happen locally, well before you get to the point of an ECS deployment. You say this works locally. So where exactly is the build phase happening that it is not working? That isn't happening on ECS.

@MarkB obviously, I pushed it to ecr and then used repository uri to create container in task definition and when I'm deploying the task I'm getting an error.I build it locally and I can say it's working.

None of that is obvious at all. It still doesn't even make any sense. The command npx prisma generate is in your Dockerfile. That runs when you do docker build on your local computer. That command shouldn't run at deployment time on ECS. The only command that should be running at deployment time on ECS is your ENTRYPOINT command of sh -c node server.js.

@MarkB I see, then it really doesn't make sense because the error occurs on the server startup

Are you providing different CMD or ENDPOINT values in your ECS task definition?

@MarkB Yes! I was deploying task definition a lot of times and one them I set entry point command in container configuration, I deleted it, now there's no error.Thank you!
